# Login boot loop in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04

I tried to upgrade my pc from Ubuntu 16.04.4 to 18.04 but while installation  my screen locked and when i tried to login ,message showing on login something like " invalid authentication " i forgot the exact word. So i didnt interfere and think after installation it will take the login and i leave the system as it is for next 2 hours , again when i move the cursor same login screen with same message showing on screen , so i thought that the installation have been completed and i restarted the pc with hard key. Now it is showing Ubuntu 18.04 on login but when i enter password it again send me back to login screen. I tried to login many times but i cant login .

Even i tried "mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak" command using ctrl+alt+f1 , but nothing works please help me , how can i login ?

Comment: use the command `sudo su` and use your user password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 broke the system completely!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029301/upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-broke-the-system-completely)

Comment: I have the same problem. Can log in via SSH but can not get to the command line on the box terminal, pressing ctrl-alt-f3 locks up the box completely. The first error message I see in /var/log/syslog is the same as from xdpyinfo
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0". This doesn't seem like a duplicate of Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 broke the system completely!  because its upgrade to 18.04.01 and the upgrade is through.